# Access to service list on docker swarm worker node

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-api

I am using docker-API module for accessing service list and the replica information. It works better in swarm-mode and on manager node. But if the app goes on worker node, it gives me the following error 
"unexpected - This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again". following is my code,

```
const Docker = require('node-docker-api').Docker
const docker = new Docker({ socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock' })
const services = await docker.service.list()
```

Is it possible to get the service list on both node by giving any options or permissions to worker node? Also Is it possible to get by running app using docker-compose or kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

As [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/nodes/) state:

> Worker nodes **don’t** participate in the Raft distributed state, make
>   scheduling decisions, or **serve the swarm mode HTTP API**.

Possible solutions:

- You may consider running only manager nodes in your swarm topology.
- Alternatively, you can use placement [constraint](https://success.docker.com/article/using-contraints-and-labels-to-control-the-placement-of-containers) `--constraint node.role==manager` for you node.js based docker service

This way your service containers would run only on manager nodes which serve the swarm mode HTTP API.